# Formatting date(); as italics in PHP

Tags: php, html, web, formatting

I'm taking a class in basic web development, for our first assignment we are to create a simple php document that displays today's date in a (Y.M.d) format.

The year is to be bold, and the months and days in italics.

I found out that you could put the bold tags directly in the date query like this;

```
echo date ("<b>Y</b>");
```

however, when I tried to do the same with the italic tag it didn't work the same way:

```
echo date ("<i>M</i>");
```

turned into "< minute >Jan", instead of just *Jan*.

I got around this by writing the code like this:

```
<?php
    echo "Today's date is: ";
    echo date ("<b>Y</b>");
    echo "<br>";
?>

<i>
<?php
    echo date ("M. ");
    echo date ("d");
?>
</i>
```

Is there a good reason why I couldn't make this work on a single line like:

```
echo date ("<b>Y</b>.<i>M</i>.<i>d</i>");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Example #2 Escaping characters in date()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this approach, you have to escape the i's, as the i is normally the format character for minutes with leading zeroes in the PHP `date` function:

```
echo date ("<\i>M</\i>");
```

The same goes for the second part of your question, that also works fine after escaping:

```
echo date ("<b>Y</b>.<\i>M</\i>.<\i>d</\i>");
```

Comment: I didn't downvote as I can't even vote yet, but I tried your solution. It makes a whole lot of sense, but it still threw a 500 server error.

is there a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: i would  be inclined to escape al the non-format characters just in case the next version of php starts using "b" in the format

Comment: syntax error was on my end, I'm sorry.
It works now, thank you! @rolfv1

Comment: @rtfm of course you could, but currently there is no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the date method **i** stands for minutes. following is from the php manual -
***i    Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59***

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hence the  is not interpreted as a tag. Hope that answers your question